# HOG features for imageset

Tags: matlab

```
numImages = numel(trainingSet.Files);
trainingFeatures = zeros(numImages, hogFeatureSize, 'single');

for i = 1:numImages
    img = readimage(trainingSet, i);
    
    img = rgb2gray(img);
    
    % Apply pre-processing steps
    img = imbinarize(img);
    
    trainingFeatures(i, :) = extractHOGFeatures(img, 'CellSize', cellSize);  
end
```

error is

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
>
> Error in Untitled3 (line 119)
> trainingFeatures(i, :) = extractHOGFeatures(img, 'CellSize', cellSize);

Comment: You don't show all your code. How do you determine `hogFeatureSize`? That is probably where the issue is.

Comment: Pleast take the [tour], read [ask] and write a [mcve]... then feel free to come back and ask a descriptive question which can be answered in a way which will be most useful to yourself and future visitors.

Comment: Also, why do you binarize the image? Gradients are computed in the grey values.

Comment: img = readimage(trainingSet, 206);

% Extract HOG features and HOG visualization

[hog_4x4, vis4x4] = extractHOGFeatures(img,'CellSize',[4 4]);

cellSize = [4 4];
hogFeatureSize = length(hog_4x4);

Comment: But Image dimensions are not equal in the image folder ,Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, according to the documentation: "HOG feature length, N, is based on the image size and the function parameter values." There is an equation there to determine the length.

Comment: @Cris Luengo: The solution is to resize all images to be the same size first

Comment: @sara: yes, that certainly makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, this part of code works now

Comment: @CrisLuengo But if there are several instances of the object in the picture, how can I locate them, any technique might help me locate the instances

Comment: @sara: That wholly depends on how the images were taken and what is in them. There are a million and one techniques for detection. I can't help you there.